# jquery click on <p> to act as a link

Tags: jquery

Here is my problem: I have a large anchor tag that links to one place, and inside this anchor I'd like a `<p>` tag that on click will link to different place. So I could do something like this:

```
function clicked()
{
window.location.href = "new link";
}
```

But it goes to link from the anchor. Do I need to use stoppropagation or something?

Comment: This shouldn't happen. The second you changed the `window.location`, all code should sieze to run.

Comment: Why are you putting a P tag inside an A tag in the first place? This seems incredibly inconvenient.

Comment: @Eirinn - I do that all the time. If you have a huge block of text & images that you want to be clickable without javascript enabled, the only way is by wrapping it all in a single giant anchor tag. Even more: now, in HTML5, even **the rules** say that we're allowed to put block level elements in an anchor rag!

Comment: It's jquery mobile, and I am putting it inside a button; button links to one place, but I need "Add To Cart" inside it to link somewhere else.

Comment: @Joseph wow i didn't know that :) It's deffinitely not xhtml! Personally i use a div and append a click event to it. If people have javascript disabled they're asking for trouble anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just return false from your callback function:

```
$('#huge-link .some-paragraphs').click(function(){
    window.location. = "new link";
    return false;
});
```